# How to fix the 404 page not found issue in codeignter 4

Tags: php, apache, xampp, codeigniter-4

The route is not working properly

routes.php

```
$routes->get('(:any)', 'Pages::view/$1');
```

pages.php

```
public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        if (! is_file(APPPATH . 'Views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
            throw new \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException($page);
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        return view('templates/header', $data)
            . view('pages/' . $page)
            . view('templates/footer');
    }
```

But it gives me 404 page not found error how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the URL you're trying to access look like?

Comment: Hi, @steven7mwesigwa this is the url http://localhost:8080/pages/view

Comment: Do you have auto-routing enabled or not?

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa is enabled $routes->setAutoRoute(true);

Comment: Do you have a `$routes->setDefaultNamespace(...)` set?

Comment: Yes @steven7mwesigwa $routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');